# Scheme: variable assignment

Tags: variables, if-statement, scheme, variable-assignment

A bucket is a sentence of balls ex: R W W B R R R G B.

Each ball color has a value ex: R (red = 3) W (white = 1)

The procedure required takes two parameters bucket1 and bucket2 and compares the values of the two buckets and outputs which one has a higher value or if its a tie. Used in this procedure is another procedure called bucket-val which calculates the value of the bucket.

I am trying to create a variable within the procedure called buck1 and buck2 to simplify the code when I do my if statements at the bottom. However I get the error:

***let: bad syntax (not an identifier and expression for a binding) in: (buck1)***

```
(define (bucket-val bucket)
  (+ (* (count-balls 'R bucket) (ball-val 'R))
     (* (count-balls 'W bucket) (ball-val 'W))
     (* (count-balls 'B bucket) (ball-val 'B))
     (* (count-balls 'G bucket) (ball-val 'G))))


(define (judge bucket1 bucket2)
  (lambda(buck1 buck2)
    (let ([buck1] (bucket-val bucket1))
      ([buck2] (bucket-val bucket2)))
    (if (equal? b1 b2 'truuuue))))
```

Answer (score 2):

First off. Syntax-wise the brackets `[]` and `()` have the same meaning. Thus if you want to add `3` and `5` you could write `[+ 3 5] ; ==> 8`. Schemers use different ones just to make some code clearer. In addition to that I'd say indentation is the most important skill to master and you should use an editor that does it for you. I Use DrRacket, but if you are more a Emacs person you should add the support for Scheme.

There are a lot of issues with your code, mostly because of extra/missing parentheses. eg. your `let`  which is the source of your error:

```
(let ([buck1]                     ; make variable buck1 as ??
      (bucket-val bucket1))       ; make variable bcuket-val as bucket1
  ([buck2] (bucket-val bucket2))) ; call buck2 and call the result
```

Notice you mix `[` and `(`? The body calls a procedure and calls the result. In Algol languages you get the same if you do `buck()(bucket-val, bucket1)`

The `if` is not correct and it is outside the `let` and thus they can not use the local variables they created. Instead you try to compare 3 values with `equal?` which would not work and you lack a consequent and a alternative expression (then/else). Some of the implementations might not fail there, but it is not portable Scheme code.

In your description you do not mention that your procedure returns a procedure that does the job when called. The double `lambda` dictates that. `(define (test x) (lambda ...))` is the same as `(define test (lambda (x) (lambda ...))))`, thus a procedure returning a procedure and not "which one has the higher value".